# Average power of load connected to an ideal transformer

Tags: circuit-analysis, transformer, ideal, reflection

[image]

Where does the 1/2 come from in the power equation?

Answer (score 1):

This is, hopefully, just enough of an answer to get you to figure it out yourself.

- Your voltage is given as a cosine function.
- What is its peak voltage?
- What is its RMS voltage?
- What is the RMS current?
- What happens when you ...?

---

As you have realised (indicated in the comments) in the question we are using \$ I_L \$ which is the peak value of a cosine waveform. The RMS value (required for the power calculation) is \$ \frac {1}{\sqrt 2} I_L \$.

Since \$ P = I^2R \$ we get \$ P_L = \left (\frac {1}{\sqrt 2} I_{pk} \right )^2 R_L = \frac {1}{2} I_{pk}^2 R_L  \$ as written in the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/206621)

Comment: @Roh. I understood exactly what I was doing as did the OP who got more than enough information to solve the problem him/herself. I wasn't looking for more details from the OP, I was prompting the OP as indicated in the first sentence. Now that the OP has worked it out I've completed the answer.

Comment: `Now that the OP has worked it out I've completed the answer.` Consider using a (de-?!)spoiler.